# How to write [^<delim>] in a generic way in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to write a regex that would pull out content like that of a perl quoted string.  I.e.:

```
qx...x
```

So I tried

```
/q(?<delim>.)                            # group 1
 (?<content>                             # group 2
   (?:                                   # group 3
     (?:\g{delim}(*PRUNE)(?!)|[^\\])++   # group 4
   | \\.
   )*+
 )
 \g{delim}
/xm
```

But that caused the finding of delim to not just break out of the 4th group, but all the others as well.  Using *THEN instead of *PRUNE acts just like if I didn't use anything at all.  I'm thinking either *THEN is just a way to prevent backtracking as if the stuff before it is atomic.  Not so useful in this case.

I want to be able to say, "if you find \g{delim}, skip all of the rest of the alternatives in the current group, and continue with alternatives out side of that group.  E.g. make the current group fail and check to see if the outer group can succeed.

If it was a specific char (say %), I could do `[^%\\]++` in place of group 4.  As in:

```
/q%                                      # group 1
 (?<content>                             # group 2
   (?:                                   # group 3
     [^%\\]++                            # group 4
   | \\.
   )*+
 )
 %
/xm
```

But I want it generic.

Any ideas?

For now, ignore that braces, parentheses and brackets are not matched in the same way.  The open delimiter is to be the same as the closing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a variation of `(?:(?!PAT).)*`.

```
/
   q (?<delim>.)
   (?: \\ (?: \\ | \g{delim} )
   |   (?: (?! \g{delim} ) [^\\] )+
   )
   \g{delim}
/sx
```

Like yours, doesn't handle whitespace after `q` or balanced delimieters (`q{...}`).

Comment: @amon, heh, hadn't noticed he used `/m`. But yeah, `/m` modifies the behaviour of `^` and `$` (neither of which are present), while `/s` modifies the behaviour of `.`.

Comment: Oops, typo. :P  Thanks.  That's so obvious now.